# “I am sleepy” in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct way to say “I am sleepy” in Esperanto?

Google translate insists — erroneously — on “Mi dormas” (I am sleeping / I sleep), but that’s not what I’m looking for. A person that is sleepy doesn’t sleep.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The esperanto affix *-em-* indicates a *tendendy or inclination* toward whatever the root refers to. So, "sleepy" can be expressed as *dormema* (as an adjective). So, *Mi estas dormema*.

You can find a list of affixes in Esperanto at [Word-Building with Esperanto Affixes](http://literaturo.org/HARLOW-Don/Esperanto/affixes.html).

Also see [*dormema* on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dormema).

Comment: Aha, of course! I’ll have to brush up on my affixes.

Answer (score 5):

*Sleepy* means “a little bit tired”, so another option could be *laceta*.

Comment: Sleepy can also mean "tired" or even "**very** tired" (about to fall asleep). I suspect those meanings could be even more prevalent than "**a little bit** tired". Dunno whether there are regional differences.

Answer (score 4):

*Mi sentas min dormema. Mi dormemas. Mi sentas dormemon. Mi volas/volus dormi. Mi baldaŭ ekdormos. Mi jam preskaŭ dormas. Mi jam dormetas. Mi estas laca kaj emas dormi. Mi estas (ĝis)dorme laca. Mi bezonas dormon.*

Comment: Exactly this way. Normally the ending _-em_ has a connotation to a long-lasting tendency or inclination  but depending on the context and used verb (especially verbs like _havi, senti_) it can denote a short-lasting state. (source [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#em_kd)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that, at least in Europe, the preferred form is 'dormavida'.

Comment: I think _-avida_ as a suffix means that you have a long-term tendency towards the root (like _manĝavida_ could mean _greedy_). This is also one of the meanings of _-em_. In this case in English _sleepy_ is only a temporary inclination to sleep (ie, a bit tired) so I don’t think _dormavida_ makes sense. Maybe a better translation of _dormavida_ would be something like _sleepyhead_.

Comment: Compound words in Esperanto often have an adaptive meaning. For example, ‘vortaro’ is not just a set of words, but a DICTIONARY, and ‘arbaro’ is not just a set of trees, but a FOREST, and so on. Also, it seems to me that ‘dormema’ is more likely to describe a ‘sleepyhead’ (using the sense that you yourself acknowledge) than would ‘dormavida’, with ‘dormavida’ being, by adaptation, more suitable for focusing on the ‘momentary life-situation’ (to use the terminology of Kurt Lewin).

Answer (score 0):

Since the English Dictionary defines *sleepy* as an adjective, I would (and have) just use the adjective (*-a*) form of the word. It's simple, and perfectly understandable: the prime directive of Esperanto where ambiguity is not an issue. 
*Mi estas dorma*. - (*dorma*, *dormeta*, *dormega* ...)

Comment: I think _dorma_ is more like something related to sleep. Like a _dorma ĉambro_ would be a room for sleeping, not a sleepy room.

Comment: Mi estas dorma means I am asleep. Dormema would be the correct word to use meaning "having an inclination for sleeping."

Comment: _Mi estas dorma_ means _I am somehow related to sleep_ Out of context, it means neither _I am sleepy_ ( = _mi estas dormema_ ) nor _I am asleep_  ( = _mi estas dormanta_ )  nor _I am a sleepyhead_ ( = _mi estas dormemulo_ ) It is a _very_ ambiguous sentence, and is therefore best avoided (In fact, I have never heard it)

Comment: "-ema" is a tendency towards something, so "dormema" is a tendency towards sleep, not sleepy. "mi dormivolas" would be "I want sleep".

Answer (score 0):

What about dormivolas? The word for hungry is manĝivolas, as in "wanting food", so wouldn't dormivolas make sense for sleepy?

Answer (score -2):

It should be "mi estas dorma" or "mi estas dormema"

Comment: Can you elaborate _why_ it should be one of these?

Comment: Neither "dorma" or "dormema" would make sense in this case. Words that end in "a" are adjectives, which describe something, like the word "granda", meaning "big". "Granda domo" would be "big house". "Dorma" can be used with "ĉambro" to mean bed room (sleep room), although I generally have just heard "dormĉambro" but you could use either one.