# Kion ekzakte signifas la sufikso «-em-»?

Tags: word-meaning

Ĉu la sufikso *-em-* signifas longdaŭran tendencon al la radika vorto, aŭ ĉu nur momentan deziron por ĝi? Mi demandas pro [ĉi tiu demando](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5006/i-am-sleepy-in-esperanto) en kiu oni proponas *dormema* kiel tradukon de la angla vorto *sleepy*. *Sleepy* efektive signifas *laceta*, do ĉi tie oni klare celas la duan signifon (nur momentan deziron). Tamen se oni uzas ĝin kun aliaj radikoj oni plej verŝajne komprenus la unuan signifon. Ekzemple se iu estas *parolema* oni supozus ke ri tendencas paroli pli ol aliaj homoj dum sia tuta vivo, kaj ne ke ri ĉi-momente deziras diri ion.

Ĉu *manĝema* signifas *malsateta* aŭ ke oni ĝenerale ŝatas manĝi pli ol aliaj homoj? Aŭ ĉu ambaŭ, depende de la kunteksto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ENGLISH

I think it could be both. You already gave some examples of both uses in the question itself. [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/em.html) describes various uses of the suffix, which include the two you mentioned as well as some others. Usually the context makes it quite clear which meaning is intended.

---

ESPERANTO

Laŭ mi povas esti ambaŭ. Vi jam donis ekzemplojn de ambaŭ uzoj en la demando mem. Jen kion skribas PMEG pri la sufikso:

> **Natura tendenco**
>
> EM-vorto plej ofte montras, ke io pro sia naturo ofte
>   aŭ daŭre tendencas al la ago:
>
> mensogi → mensogema = inklina al mensogado, ofte mensoganta
>
> timi → timema = inklina al timado, ofte timanta
>
> [...]
>
> **Momenta emo**
>
> Iafoje oni uzas EM por momenta aŭ okaza deziro, aŭ por
>   pasanta bezono:
>
> Ŝi sentis fortan manĝemon. (= ... fortan malsaton.)
>
> Ĉu vi estas trinkema? (= ... soifa?)

Do povas esti ambaŭ, sed kutime pro la kunteksto la celita signifo estas sufiĉe klara.

Ankaŭ estas kelkaj aliaj uzmanieroj, kiujn PMEG priskribas. [Jen la paĝo](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/em.html).